# Can I send Push Notification to my app if I delete my app from App Store

Tags: iphone, push-notification

I have a app in AppStore which I am sending push notification.
I need to know if I can continue to send push notification to the users of the app if I delete the app from itunesconnect (AppStore).

Thanks,

Yasin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are removing the app from sale but leaving it as an entry configured for Push then you can.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you explain to me what do you mean by "entry configured"

Comment: Leave it in provisioning and on the App Store, though removed from sale.